# Sanitize HTML and close incomplete tags

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sanitize

`sanitize()` in `ApplicationHelper` doesn't close tags.

```
s = "<a href='http://example.com'>incomplete"
sanitize(s, :tags => ['a', 'p'])
```

The above snippet leaves the string as is. How could I force it to append a closing `</a>` or at least strip the `<a>` altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated answer is

```
 s = "<a href='http://example.com'>incomplete"
 html = sanitize(s, tags: %w[a p])
 Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html).to_html
```

Comment: The last line on its own worked great for me, and closed the unclosed tags too.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a proper HTML parser to do this. I'd recommend Nokogiri for the job:

```
require 'nokogiri'
# ...
s = "<a href='http://example.com'>incomplete"
Nokogiri::HTML::fragment(sanitize(s, :tags => ['a', 'p'])).to_xml
# => "<a href=\"http://example.com\">incomplete</a>"
```

This will always return valid XML. Of course you can package that into your own helper method for easier usage.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm seeing `TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer` in response to that, it works with plain text. This is Nokogiri 1.5.2.

Comment: @mahemoff: `Nokogiri::HTML::fragment("<a href='http://example.com'>incomplete").to_xml` works fine here. What's the actual tag soup you tried?

Comment: Actually, it looks like it's the second argument to sanitize. As in the original question, the allowed tags needs to be in a hash, keyed on :tags =>. `Nokogiri::HTML::fragment(sanitize('test <a href="http://example.com">incomplete', :tags => ['a', 'p'])).to_xml` does work.

Comment: BTW I just noticed, while dealing with i18n, that `to_xml` might be better off as `to_html`. The latter was escaping unicode entities like &#123.